# mysql, make a dynamic custom alias

Tags: mysql

in table I have a several columns which are related to address ( street, city, zip code etc.)

How define 'constant alias' in table when set a query like

```
select adress from table  ;
```

?
which will replace by query:

```
select concat( zip_code, ' ', city, '; ', street ) adress from table
```

I would like to prevent using concat statement in each query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a computed column, but this is not supported in MySQL. Instead you can create a view that includes all the columns form your original table and the extra column. In your queries you can the select from the view instead of the original table.

```
 CREATE VIEW mytable_with_address AS
 SELECT
     col1,
     col2,
     ...
     coln,
     CONCAT(zip_code, ' ', city, '; ', street) AS address
FROM mytable
```

Comment: I create a view only once and will be remembered in the database?

Comment: Yes, you create the view only once.

Answer (score 2):

The way is to create a view:

```
create view table2 as
  select concat( zip_code, ' ', city, '; ', street ) as adress 
  from table
```

Then you can select from view:

```
select adress from table2
```